# Use Python bottle server to receive FileEntity of a POST request from Android

Tags: android, python, bottle

On Android phone, I used setEntity() to put the FileEntity to the POST request.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(f, "application/x-gzip");
reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
reqEntity.setChunked(true);
post.addHeader("X-AethersNotebook-Custom", configuration.getCustomHeader());
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
```

When using bottle, tried this but it is not working

```
f = request.body
gzipper = gzip.GzipFile( fileobj= f )
content = gzipper.read()
```

The content will be an empty string. So I tried to look at request.forms and request.files. Both of them have no key and value.

```
request.files.keys()
request.forms.keys()
```

When searching, I read about the entity: "a request MAY transfer entity" and the entity has entity-header and entity-value. So it may be something like file-content = e.get(entity-header).

Comment: In Bottle, `request.body` contains the raw, unparsed request body. If it is empty, then no data was sent to the server. I'd search the error at client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that code, the phone send file using chunked encoding. Because py-bottle does not support chunked enconding, the solution here is rewrite the android to send file as body of POST request.